# HOW: Apache Camel, Quartz timer usage

Tags: apache, quartz-scheduler, apache-camel

im working on a project at work.

ive defined a route that works correctly,
but im having problems getting quarts to act the way i want it.

what ive got:

```
from uri="quartz://FTP/SUNDSVALL.COPY?cron=0+0+08+?+*+MON-SUN"/
```

but that comes with an error when its supposed to fire and dosent run the route defined.

what i want is a timer that fires the route every day at 0800 hours.

Comment: what is the error that you are seeing?  also, include your full route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for everyday at 8AM, this should work...

```
from("quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0+8+*+*+*").to("log:+++IT WORKED+++");
```